# AngularJS make button ng-required false when ng-click is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m dealing with an AngularJS project in which I need to update 
the behaviour of a button. I´m very new to AngularJS so i´m struggling quite a lot

Is there any way that my button becomes `ng-required="false"` when `ng-click="addItemToCollection(item)"` 
is triggered, which means when the user clicks the button,  changes the value of to `ng-required="false"`?

Tried a bunch of approaches but all of them were a total fail.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" ng-required="true" name="no-validate"
        ng-click="addItemToCollection(item)" 
        type="button" btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0" 
  ><i class="somethingicon"></i><span> Action</span><span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm" ng-required="true" name="no-validate"
        ng-click="addItemToCollection(item)" 
        type="button" btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0" 
  ><i class="somethingicon"></i><span> Action</span><span>
</button>

<button class="btn btn-sm" ng-required="true" name="no-validate"
        ng-click="addItemToCollection(item)" 
        type="button" btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0" 
  ><i class="somethingicon"></i><span> Action</span><span>
</button>
```

Basically I need that when at least ONE of the buttons of the list is clicked, they all become not-required, so the form can be submitted, if none of them has been clicked, then it should prevent the form. thanks.

One of my initial approaches is to look into the main $scope object and check if there is a item added to the collection, make all the buttons not required, but again, didn´t work.

Comment: what do you expect to get with marking button required?

Comment: On button click what you want to required? Is there any feilds for marking as not required.

Comment: Basically I need that when at least ONE of the buttons of the list is clicked, they all become not-required, so the form can be submitted, if none of them has been clicked, then it should prevent the form. thanks.

Comment: @Dolar I have updated my question, it was not very clear.

Comment: You can use radio button for it. Because as per your requirement you want to clieck on one of button from many of it and after that you want to submit the form.And give css like button.

Comment: The `btn-checkbox-false` and `btn-checkbox-true` directives are not core AngularJS directives. Does the code use third-party directives? The  `ng-required` directive does not work with buttons or checkboxes (unless that functionality has been added by a third party).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ng-required` directive does not work with buttons.

Perhaps your intention is to disable the <kbd>submit</kbd> button:

```html
<button ng-click="addItemToCollection(item)" type="button">
   <i class="somethingicon"></i><span> Action</span>
</button>

<button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="!somethingAdded">Submit</button>
```

```js
$scope.somethingAdded = false;

$scope.addItemToCollection= function(item) {
    $scope.somethingAdded = true;
    // ...
    // add item to collection
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-disabled` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one javascript object

```
$scope.buttons = {
   button1:true,
   button2:true,
   button3:true
};
$scope.addItemToCollection(item,button){
  if(button==1){
   $scope.buttons.button2 =false;
   $scope.buttons.button2 =false;
  }
  ....
}
```

in HTML

```
"ng-required="{{buttons.button1}}"
"ng-required="{{buttons.button2}}"
"ng-required="{{buttons.button3}}"

ngclick="addItemToCollection(item,1)"
ngclick="addItemToCollection(item,2)"
ngclick="addItemToCollection(item,3)"
```